# how to style all windows dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I want to style all windows in app.xaml but it don't work !! every other control style work but Window don't.

i create themes and i want to change themes dynamically ,everything works perfect when i clear application ResourceDictionary  and add selected  theme  dictionary but window style don't.

this is a Simple XAML code of what i'm doing :

```
<Application x:Class="TestWindowStyle.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWindowStyle"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="hello"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define an implicit style for each of your derived window types, e.g.:

```
<Style x:Key="myWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Title" Value="hello"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="local:MainWindow" BasedOn="{StaticResource myWindowStyle}" />
<Style TargetType="local:Window1" BasedOn="{StaticResource myWindowStyle}" />
<Style TargetType="local:Window2" BasedOn="{StaticResource myWindowStyle}" />
```

At runtime the type of your window is for example `MainWindow` and then the implicit style for the `Window` base class won't be picked up automatically.